# How to get value from list of classes?

Tags: c#, list

I have such class

```
class single_request
{
    public int _time_service { get; set; }
}
```

And such list, in which I have added some of these classes.

```
    List<single_request> list_Srequests =   new List<single_request>();
```

Eventually I just need to sum all `_time_service` from classes, which located in the list_Srequests . I tried to such code, using [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx)

```
foreach (int time_service in list_Srequests.SelectMany(v => v._time_service))
{
    total_time_SingleReq =+ time_service;
}
```

But It says, there is an error in the first line, something like `try to identify explicitly`. What is wrong here? And if possible, provide true one.

Comment: how does `periodic_request` looks like?

Comment: @Rocketq - Use `Select` in place of `SelectMany`. Updated in an answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simpy use [Sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method provided by LINQ -

```
total_time_SingleReq = list_Srequests.Sum(v => v._time_service)
```

**Problem in your code is -**

You should be using `Select` in place of `SelectMany`.

Also shorthand operator for addition is incorrect. It should be `+=` instead of `=+`.
Using `+=` will set `total_time_SingleReq` to last loop value of `time_service`.

```
foreach (int time_service in list_Srequests.Select(v => v._time_service))
{
    total_time_SingleReq += time_service;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use Sum

```
total_time_SingleReq = list_Srequests.Sum(x=>x._time_service);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
List<single_request> list_Srequests =   new List<single_request>();

int totalvalue = 0;
foreach(single_request aRequest in list_Srequests)
{
  int currentvalue = aRequest._time_service ;
  totalvalue += currentvalue ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this kind of answer, because I will need it later.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest and simple solution is to use [LINQ Sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535184%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
total_time_SingleReq = list_Srequests.Sum(req=>req._time_service);
```

For better understanding check [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535184%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#code-snippet-2)